# Проблемы с кодировкой БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, кодировка, utf-8, mysql

У меня хостинг от MNS. Кодировка домена выставлена **UTF-8**. В phpMyAdmin MySQL-кодировка сервера: **UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)**, сопоставление соединения с MySQL: `utf8_general_ci`. Сравнение БД и таблицы, в которую ведётся запись, тоже `utf8_general_ci`. Но всё равно почти вся кириллица записывается и селектиться как в виде вопросительных знаков. 
В чём может быть проблема? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким прежде?

Comment: Если бы всё так просто было…
Записывается как ?±?‹???‚???°?? ?»???????†?° ?±?µ?????‚ ?????????·?? ?‡?°?‰?? в БД, чтобы также вывести на сайте надо ещё iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $text) сделать, хотя это полностью противоречит всем выставленным кодировкам…

Comment: сомневаюсь что все(апач,мускул,пхп) настроены на utf-8.Проверьте внимательно кодировку страницыы еще.

Answer (score 2):

Да с такой проблемой сталкивались, я думаю, многие. В том числе и я. Но несмотря на то, что а таблицу кириллица так записывается, при её чтении из таблицы средствами PHP все будет нормально, т.е весь "закракозябренный" текст становится таким, каким был до записи в таблицу. Ну, а если все равно ничего не получится, то перед всеми модификациями таблиц средствами SQL, выполните вот такой запрос:

```
SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8
```

Или такой:

```
SET NAMES "utf8"'
```

Answer (score 1):

еще нужно чтобы файлы php были в утф-8 и сервер слал заголовок утф-8